# Is there a swift way of finding matching lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, matching

I have a couple of groups of lists, and I would like examine how many overlapping values they have.

I have managed to do this with a couple of nested loops, but I'm wondering if there is a more runtime-efficient way, or even a function to process multiple 'groups' at once returning arrays with the most overlapping values.

My code looks so far like this:

```
group1 = [['a','b','c'], ['1','2','3'], ['x','y','z','w'],['10','20','30','40']]
group2 = [['a','b','x','z'], ['1','2','3','4','5'], ['x','y','z','q','p'],['10','50','60','70']]
group3 = [['a','b','c','x','1'], ['1','2','3','4','6'], ['y','z','w','5'],['10','20','60','70']]

def match(grp1, grp2):
    for arr1 in grp1:
        for arr2 in grp2:
            overlap = len(arr1) + len(arr2) - len(set(arr1+arr2))
            if overlap > 0:
                print(overlap, overlap/len(arr1), overlap/len(arr2), arr1, arr2)

match(group1, group2)
print()
match(group1, group3)
print()
match(group3, group2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `set()` and want to abstract this some more, you can use the `set.intersection()` method. For instance:

```
s1 = set(['a', 'b', 'c'])
s2 = set(['a', 'b', 'x', 'z'])
print(list(s1.intersection(s2))) # ['a', 'b']
print(len(list(s1.intersection(s2)))) # 2
```

Once you have a feel for this on your data, you can use `itertools.combinations` to run intersections on combinations of lists (turned into sets).